# PHP Twitter Search API

Tags: php, twitter

Im looking for a way of running a Twitter Search (Automated via CRON) that will search for a list of terms held in a text file.

Once it finds those terms I want it to write to results to a text file. Can anyone suggest anything? Simpler the better.

#### Edit

Seems I may not have been too clear,

I want to be able to Search Twitter, based on the contents of a CSV file.

The results should be cached, save to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 3 steps:

1. set up a php script to run periodically (if you are using cpanel, you should find a GUI option to do so)
2. create a text file that contains the terms you want to search
3. the script will read the file ([file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [fread](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)) and then search for the terms on twitter (try [php-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/php-twitter/))

Answer (score 0):

What is you question exactly? How to read from a file? How to use the twitter api? How to cron you script?

Comment: The question is, how do I write a Twitter Search to read in Text file for its search terms.